# How do I center the text in the header row of an element-ui table?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I tried centering the text in the header of my element-ui table via:

```
<el-table :data="myTable" header-row-style="text-align: center;">
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't have the desired effect. How do I center the names of the columns?

Comment: Could you post a small working example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue)?

Comment: @Titulum : I tried it in https://codesandbox.io/s/element-ui-table-header-issue-q808d but I don't know how to get the import of element-ui working in that CodeSandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

header-row-style takes an object or a function as an attribute value. it does not take a string.

So you can try it

```
<el-table :data="myTable" :header-row-style="{textAlign: 'center'}">
```

Comment: To me this doesn't seem to change anything. See https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-hamilton-q808d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark or not the textAlign is set to `right` or `center` it renders the same.

Comment: see https://codesandbox.io/s/element-ui-table-header-issue-1jdvu 
:header-row-style="{textAlign: 'center'}"

Answer (score 2):

For centering only header text, use `header-align="center"` in `<el-table-column />` as a property, for align all row + header. You can use `align="center"`:

```html
<el-table >
    <el-table-column
        label="ID"
        prop="id"
        header-align="center"
        align="right">
    </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

##### References

- [Element UI - Table-Column Attributes](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-column-attributes)

- [An example of using the Table-Column attribute](https://codepen.io/Mihalidis/pen/ZEaWdeP)

Answer (score 0):

to centering the text in the header of element-ui table you can use `:header-cell-style="{textAlign: 'center'}` .

you can try:

`<el-table :data="myTable" :header-cell-style="{textAlign: 'center'}">`